# what approach will experts choose to follow in this type of condition using LINQ silverlight .edmx

Tags: silverlight, linq, ado.net-entity-data-model

- there are 500 tables, some large, some small,
- all have different number of columns
- they may or may not have a relation between them

### i must

- select

  - "user specified columns" from
  - "user specified table" where
  - "user specified condition" on "user specified column"

### my solution was

- just write functions/queries/stored procedures for all of them :-)

but well thats gonna take an eternity considering the fact that silver doesnot support system.data which would have provided a simple/crude solution of constructing the select command as a string and then pass it to the dataadaptor

### note

this question might seem fimiliar to the previous one i asked

### but here

- i am interested in any feasible/professional solution

### and also note

- please do not comment that this scenario can never arise practically, i know that just wondering what if!

thnks

Comment: do you require linq or are you open to other orms like nhibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look in to having Silveright use WCF RIA Services and NHibernate.

NHibernate offers the ability to compose expressions on the fly and dynamically map to objects.  Consider the approach found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1762263/100988) for building your

```
select "user specified columns" from
"user specified table" where
"user specified condition" on "user specified column"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [BLToolkit](http://bltoolkit.net/) to create your DAL and then use WCF service to push data to silverlight app.